# How to show date on text input after selecting on datetime picker?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to show date on the text input after user has selected a date on a datetime picker based on react-native-modal-datetime-picker library, on expo snack.

However, I cant seem to show the date once it has been selected. May I know which part of this code below did I messed up.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

export default function ShareExample() {

  const [date, SetDate] = useState('');
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    SetDate(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            value={date}
            placeholder="Date..."/>
  <Button
  onPress={showDatePicker}
  title='Set Date'/>
  <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
          mode="date"
          onConfirm={handleConfirm}
          onCancel={hideDatePicker}
          />
  </View>
)
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    padding: 50
  },
  textInput:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `DateTimePickerModal`  you don't get a string value, instead, you will get a Date object which you will have to convert into a string value in order to display it in `TextInput`.

**Here is how you can do that: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/date_picker)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

export default function ShareExample() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  const getDate = () => {
    let tempDate = date.toString().split(' ');
    return date !== ''
      ? `${tempDate[0]} ${tempDate[1]} ${tempDate[2]} ${tempDate[3]}`
      : '';
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={getDate()}
        placeholder="Date..."
      />
      <Button onPress={showDatePicker} title="Set Date" />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
      <Text>{date.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 50,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 5,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```